# Cannot change inline styles when using <!DOCTYPE html>

Tags: javascript, html, styles, doctype

I am writing a script to change a buttons position when `mouseover` is called , I wasted 2 hours to figure out that if I include `<!DOCTYPE html>` at beginning then the button will not move on `mouseover`, but if I remove the `<!DOCTYPE html>` then the buttons correctly change there position.

Here's my Code: 
 `index.html`

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title>My First Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

<body>
    <h1 style="position:absolute; left:220px; top:175px; width:auto; height:210px;">Are You a Bird?    </h1>
    <div id="By" style="position:absolute; left:285px; top:235px; width:210px; 
height:210px;">
        <input type="button" value=" YES " onclick="yes()" />
    </div>
    <div ID="Bn" style="position:absolute; left:360px; top:235px; width:210px; height:210px;">
        <input type="button" value="  NO  " onmouseover="foo()" />
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

`script.js`

```
var flag=1;

function foo(){
    if(flag==1)
    {    
        Bn.style.top=90;
        Bn.style.left=500;
        flag=2;
    }
    else if(flag==2)
    {

        Bn.style.top=90;
        Bn.style.left=50;
        flag=3;
    }
    else if(flag==3)
    {
        Bn.style.top=235;
        Bn.style.left=360;
        flag=1;
    }
}
```

Why does including `<!DOCTYPE html>` cause trouble with changing the positioning of an element?

Comment: where is `yes()` defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<!DOCTYPE html>` means you are using HTML5, and it is in no way bad or evil. HTML5 offers some great features, including one of my favorites (The HTML5 Canvas).

To your code look here:

```
<input type="button" value=" YES " onclick="yes()" />
```

Notice in your JS file `yes()` is not defined.

Now to why it seems `onmouseover` does not work. Actually it's working fine, the problem lies right here:

```
Bn.style.top=90;
Bn.style.left=500;
```

Remember in CSS we need to set it as a number followed by the text "px". Like "90px". So to do this in JavaScript we use strings:

```
Bn.style.top = "90px";
Bn.style.left = "500px";
```

And it works. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/AniHouse/ppmbp3qj/) is a quick fiddle example using your code with the "#px" added.

***So why does HTML5 make it so we can't use integers?***

While without HTML5 you can change the position using either `90` or `"90px"`, with `<!DOCTYPE html>`  using integers does not work and you will need to use strings like `"90px"`. The reasoning behind this is mainly because of unit convention, it's clear pixels are used.

Comment: I stripped that part to not make this page longer and for you ease

Comment: @AsheshKumar Using HTML5 does not affect (or should not) the `onmouseover` function. In `foo()` where did you define `Bn`? Also could you provide console error messages? That would be very helpful to finding the problem.

Comment: @AsheshKumar Nevermind I noticed that `Bn` was defined in an `id`. The problem was you needed to use strings like so: `Bn.style.top = "90px";`.